# Electric motors and Internal Combustion Engines compared

Tags: motors, automotive-engineering, electric-vehicles, generator, power-generation

I know that [Internal Combustion engines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_combustion_engine) are rated in terms of peak power developed, while [electric motors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_motor) are generally specified in terms of continuous power output. Is there a good way to determine the equivalent power output between the two?

Suppose I needed to determine the minimum engine size for a 3 kVA generator set?

Comment: If you have electricity to run a motor to turn a generator, you can likely convert that electricity more efficiently. You'd need more than 3kVA to get 3kVA out.

Comment: Are you under the impression that I'm trying to build some sort of infinite energy machine?

Comment: Some Internal combustion motors are rated for continuous duty, buy one rated for 4 hp , a Honda would do.

Comment: I'm trying to extend the knowledge to general applications. Is there a rule of thumb to know what an typical internal combustion engine is capable of under a constant load?

Comment: Yes rule of thumb is to test it under conditions you need (if you can afford, or the return policy is good enough, this can work out), and if you cannot test it yourself, buy one that is rated for the conditions.

Comment: Any and every industrial engine has a published continuous rating. Most will have two or three additional ratings as well. ie continuous, med duty, light duty, and recreational in the case of marine diesel propulsion motors. The recreational rating may be more than double the continuous rating, but is limited to perhaps 500 hours per year.

Comment: Electric motors will have a duty rating as well. A drill or saw motor might have a 50% duty rating and a 5 minute max run time from cold start. The same drill with a 100% duty motor might cost five times as much money.

Comment: Genset heads play the same games. The advertised power is often the peak power that the electronics can survive, and might be available for a few seconds to start a motor. But the documentation and system fuses will be set up for much less, maybe 60-70% of nameplate rating, and then only for noncontinuous loads. Gas powered gensets with identical advertised ratings may cost anywhere from \$600 to \$5000 differing in duty cycle and continuous rating and life expectancy.